# Unity: How do I fix the players model rotation in a NetworkManager to spawn properly?

Tags: unity, rotation, unity-networking

How do I fix the players model rotation in a NetworkManager to spawn properly?

I created a game with the NetworkManager code.
Player Model is a cone I made and imported.

all works fine but when the NetworkManager spawns the player model it is sideways.
I have tried turning it in 3ds but the player remains sideways when it is spawned by NetworkManager on run, Ohterwise the model is fine in unity, and no matter how I rotate it, in or out of unity , The NetworkManager Rotates it.
All other objects attached to the main object remain with proper orientation all, All other objects including instantiated ones appear properly.

Comment: Can you show us how your character object is set up, and the code you use to spawn it?

Comment: I have added it to my description.